# ValueError when using if commands in function

Tags: python, numpy, if-statement, scipy

I'm creating some functions that I can call use keywords to call out specific functions,

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np

def HubbleParam(a, model = "None"):
    if model == "LCDM":
        Omega_L0 = 0.7
        Omega_m0 = 0.3 
        return np.sqrt( Omega_m0/a/a/a+ Omega_L0  )

    if model == "Q":
        Omega_Q0 = 0.7
        Omega_m0 = 0.3 
        return np.sqrt( Omega_m0/a/a/a + Omega_Q0/a )


def EmitterDistance(z, model = "None"):
    a = 1./(1.+z)
    if model == 'LCDM':
        integrand = 1./a/a/HubbleParam(a, model="LCDM")
        return [z , integrate.quad(integrand, a, 1.)[0] ]

    if model == "Q":
        integrand = 1/a/a/HubbleParam(a, model="Q")
        return [z, integrate.quad(inta, a, 1.)[0] ]

z = np.linspace(0.,5., 1000)

print EmitterDistance(z, model="LCDM")
```

When trying to print this array, this is returned,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File      "/Users/alexandres/Desktop/Formation_Galaxies/Homework1/FoG_HW1.py", line 95, in <module>
    print EmitterDistance(z, model="LCDM")
  File "/Users/alexandres/Desktop/Formation_Galaxies/Homework1/FoG_HW1.py", line 87, in EmitterDistance
    return [z , integrate.quad(integrand, a, a)[0] ]
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 315, in quad
points)
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 364, in _quad
    if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
[Finished in 0.5s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u     "/Users/alexandres/Desktop/Formation_Galaxies/Homework1/FoG_HW1.py"]
[dir: /Users/alexandres/Desktop/Formation_Galaxies/Homework1]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

or more importantly

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In `EmitterDistance()` your first argument to `integrate.quad()` should a function. But it is an array, instead.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error results when you use an array in a context that expects a scalar value.  It is testing `a != -Inf` in an `if` expression.  `a` and `b` here are the boundary points of the integration.  They should be scalars, not arrays.  But you are calling `quad` with:

```
 quad(integrand, a, a)
```

`a` here is `a = 1./(1.+z)`, and `z` is the array produced by `linspace`.

`integrand` also looks problematic.  It is array derived from `a`.  It should, instead, be a function.  Something that takes a scalar and returns a value.  `HubbleParam` might work, or a `lambda` or function def using it.