# Integration with variable as an integration limit ( python)

Tags: python, scipy, quad

I need to perform an integration with python but with one of the limits being a variable, and not a number (from 0 to z).

I tried the following:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy.integrate import quad

    def  I(z,y,a):    #function I want to integrate

      I = (a*(y*(1+z)**3+(1-y))**(0.5))**(-1)

      return I

    def dl(z,y,a):  #Integration of I

      dl = quad(I, 0, z, args =(z,y,a))

      return dl
```

The problem I have is that `dl(z,y,a)` gives me an array, so whenever I want to plot or evaluate it, I obtain the following:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

I don't know if there is any solution for that.Thanks in advanced

Comment: Are you integrating on variable y or z? The function you are integrating also contains z, it may be less confusing if you can include an example of your usage.

Comment: I am integrating over z. Yes your'e right, the function also contains z, maybe this is one of the problems, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to call `quad` with your `I` is:

```
In [20]: quad(I, 0, 10, args=(1,2))
Out[20]: (0.6984886554222364, 1.1361829471531105e-11)
```

As Longwen points out, the first argument to `I` is the `z` that `quad` varies.  The `(y,a)` are parameters that `quad` passes on to `I` without change.

But you got the error because you tried using an array as the `z` boundary

```
In [21]: quad(I, 0, np.arange(3), args=(1,2))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-fbbfa9c0cd3f> in <module>()
----> 1 quad(I, 0, np.arange(3), args=(1,2))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points, weight, wvar, wopts, maxp1, limlst)
    313     if (weight is None):
    314         retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
--> 315                        points)
    316     else:
    317         retval = _quad_weight(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel,

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    362 def _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points):
    363     infbounds = 0
--> 364     if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
    365         pass   # standard integration
    366     elif (b == Inf and a != -Inf):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

[ValueError when using if commands in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41868099/valueerror-when-using-if-commands-in-function) - another recent question trying to do the same thing, use an array as an integration boundary.  That post gave more of the error traceback, so it was easier to identify the problem.

---

If it hadn't been for this ValueError, your 3 term `args` would have produced a different error:

```
In [19]: quad(I, 0, 10, args=(10,1,2))
....
TypeError: I() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** In your code you should only your `args` argument as `agrs=(y, a)`, z should not be included. Then you can access the result of integration by indexing the first element of the returned tuple.

Actually `quad` returns a tuple. The first element in the tuple is the reuslt you want. Since I cannot get your code run without problem, I wrote some short codes instead. I am not sure if this is what you want:

```
def I(a):
    return lambda z, y: (a*(y*(1+z)**3+(1-y))**(0.5))**(-1)

def dl(z, y, a):
    return quad(I(a), 0, z, args=(y))

print(dl(1,2,3)[0])
```

Results:

```
0.15826362868629346
```

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I need, I don't really understand why you don't put the variable  'a' in args() . Anyway, thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Brny `args` should contain the arguments except for the one you are integrating over. In my case, the function I(a) actually returns function that takes two arguments y and z. When I pass it to the `quad` function, it actually only takes one additional argument (y) except for the variable I am integrating (z). That is why I only include y in `args`. But it does the same thing as your codes.

Comment: Okay, I got it.   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `quad` accepts vector valued integration boundaries. So in this case you'll actually have to either loop over `z` or use `np.vectorize`.

Answer (score 0):

The Python consideration is that an empty list (or iterable) is false when casted to a booleans. Imagine you are listing something.

As you are doing computing you may consider the Zero vector, [0,0,0] which in linear alegbra may be considered as zero but is not an empty list.

You error seems to come from an not null checking.
As other answers suggest you miscalled a function and provided an array where a number was expected.